# Perform action based on one of three choices in a more Object Oriented way

Tags: swift, oop

I need to perform a calculation based on one of three options the user can select, I haven't created any real code because I'm not sure what method to use that is more common in a more OOP than my spaghetti code below.

What would be the most common way to keep track of `measurementType` based on the following code? I have never used Enums in any language and I was wondering if this would be a good fit for them.

Any suggestion?

```
var measurementType:String = ""

let pounds = "Pounds"
let kilograms = "Kilograms"
let quantity = "Quantity"

// User selection
measurementType = pounds

// Perform calculation based on user's selection
if measurementType == kilograms{
    print("Calculation for Kilograms")
}else if(measurementType == pounds){
    print("Calculation for Pounds")
}else{
    print("Calculation for Quantity")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't really call that spaghetti code, but sure, you can use `enum` in this case. Also, you might want to use a `switch` statement instead of multiple `if-else`.

```
enum MeasurementType {
    case Pounds
    case Kilograms
    case Quantity
}

var measurementType: MeasurementType = .Pounds

switch measurementType {
    case .Pounds:
        print("Calculation for Pounds")
    case .Kilograms:
        print("Calculation for Kilograms")
    case .Quantity:
        print("Calculation for Quantity")
    default:
        print("?")
        //or use () / break if the default doesn't interest you
}
```

Comment: @ Sebastian - Thanks, that helps a lot. Now let's make this a little more interesting, if the user selection will be happening in a second viewController and then the result will be sent to the main viewController via delegation where the action will take place, would `enums` would still make sense? If yes, how would I check the status of `MeasurementType ` in my main viewController?

Comment: Sure, you could still use enum. Just make sure you declare it outside the scope of any class or function, and it will be available everywhere. Not sure I understand what you mean by checking the status of MeasurementType, but you could access it the same as before.

Comment: @ Sebastian - Sorry about the confusin, what I meant is to do the check with the `switch` in the main viewController to see what was sent view the delegate method (what the user selected in second controller). I guess I could also create a helper class to include the `enum`.

Comment: @fs_tigre - sure, I don't see why not.

Comment: There's no need for a helper class here. The enum can exist on its own, outside of any class. You can have files that just define enums.

Comment: @  Rob Napier - Sorry but I have heard that global variables are evil etc., but I guess `enums` are some how statics, right? Rob, what do you mean with `You can have files that just define enums`? Thanks

Comment: @fs_tigre - enums are actually types, same as classes or structs

Answer (score 2):

`measurementType` is not a good type. Pounds and kilograms are parallel. Mass (*) and quantity are parallel. But pounds, kilograms, and quantity are not parallel. This is the kind of code that makes you lose your [Mars probe](http://articles.latimes.com/1999/oct/01/news/mn-17288).

First, if this is targeting iOS 10 or macOS 10.12, look at the new [`Measurement` type](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/238/). It is designed to help in exactly this kind of situation (and has a lot of powerful localized formatting features). But let's assume you can't use that, or just don't want to (its syntax is a little heavy at times). How would we build this cleanly?

```
enum MassUnit {
    case kilogram(Double)
    case pound(Double)
}

enum Measurement {
    case quantity(Int)
    case mass(MassUnit)
}

let measurement = Measurement.mass(.pound(10))

switch measurement {
case .quantity(let count):
    print("Calculation for Quantity")

case .mass(.kilogram(let mass)):
    print("Calculation for kilogram")

case .mass(.pound(let mass)):
    print("Calculation for pound")

}
```

Note how this combines the value of the measurement with its type. These are no longer separate, so they can't get mixed up and can be passed as a single value. Notice also that this allows mass to be a Double while a count must be an Int. The compiler will also validate that you have considered all possible cases and give you an error if you forget one.

We can go further with this of course. We could remove code duplication by hoisting conversions into the type. Then we probably don't even need to separate "calculation for kilogram" and "calculation for pound". For example:

```
extension MassUnit {
    var kilograms: Double {
        switch self {
        case .kilogram(let kg): return kg
        case .pound(let lb): return 0.454 * lb
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to expand to have grams or stone or whatever other mass units you want, while easily performing all calculations in kilograms when desired (without losing the original unit information for times when that's useful).

This approach also allows direct math on masses (which may also eliminate your "kilogram vs pound" switch legs). You can define addition like this:

```
extension MassUnit {
    static func + (lhs: MassUnit, rhs: MassUnit) -> MassUnit {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.kilogram(lhsValue), .kilogram(rhsValue)):
            return .kilogram(lhsValue + rhsValue)

        case let (.pound(lhsValue), .pound(rhsValue)):
            return .pound(lhsValue + rhsValue)

        case let (.kilogram(lhsValue), .pound(_)):
            return .kilogram(lhsValue + rhs.kilograms)

        case (.pound, .kilogram):
            return rhs + lhs
        }
    }
}
```

So kg+kg=kg, lb+lb=lb, lb+kg=kg. And of course you can write similar operations for multiplying by a Double or the like. Once you go down this road a little, you'll find it extremely flexible.

(*) We will ignore pedantic arguments at this point about whether pounds are a force measurement and decree that "pound" and "pound-mass" are synonyms.

Comment: @ Rob - Wow! Thanks a lot for the good information and well implemented code here. I'm leaving `Sebastian` answer but your answer deserves more than a thumbs up vote. Is there a way to vote up and give you points or something like that here in Stackoverflow?